# ASP.NET : EF 5.X - Conversion Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to pull information out of a database and then add the values together. I have no issue when pulling the information out of the database however, there seems to be a conversion error when I am adding the values.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Outside where I am querying I have this:

```
var addition = 0.0;
```

When I pull the data out the Database, I try to add the value to this:

```
addition = addition + clear;
```

Both `addition` and `clear` are the same datatype which is why I am confused why it would need to do any conversion? (both Double's).

Extra information: `clear` comes from :

```
var clear = tbl_detail[a].AmountCleared;
```

and `tbl_detail` is an array of the queried data.

Could anyone possibly reference why I am receiving this error? Or possibly point me in the right direction because I am not understand why:

1. It needs to convert anything since they're the same datatype and
2. What a cast actually is because Google isn't really helping me when I am searching any of this.

Comment: Try addition = addition + clear.Value

Comment: `Double?` and `double` are not the same data type. `Double?` is actually `Nullable<Double>.

Comment: wow, so all I was missing this whole time was `.Value` at the end... if you put that in an answer @pλul I will mark it. Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AmountCleared is a nullable double (double?). You could do this:

```
addition += clear.Value
```

This will throw a InvalidOperationException if the Clear is null.

[Edit] You could also use `addition += clear ?? 0.0` if you would like to use a default value for nulls.

You could change AmoutCleared into a double. I suspect that you created this through a designer or database first and used 'allow nulls' on the database column, which is why your are getting a nullable type. So you would have to change the database type to not 'allow nulls'. But without seeing the definition of the data type tbl_detail[a] or knowing how you generated it, I cannot help you much further.

Answer (score 1):

AmountCleared is actually a Nullable type (Nullable) which allows C# value types to represent SQL server Nulls (Value types can never be assigned the value of null)

You can get the underlying value of the nullable type by simply calling .Value property, however this will throw a InvalidOperationException if the value is null, you can check if it has a value by calling .HasValue

Try this:

```
addition += clear.HasValue ? clear.Value : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

clear is a nullable value
to safely manipulate nullables use:

```
if(clear.hasValue)
{
    addition += clear.Value;
}
```

You can also use the null coalescing operator `??` to fallback to a default value if the provided value is null

```
addition += clear ?? 0.0;
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `addition += clear ?? 0.0`.

Comment: it really depends on what variable is the nullable one but seeing the edit sayin that clear comes from the database, i now tend to agree with you.
btw this is the reason i'm against using var as it's easy to type, but makes code harder to read later.

Comment: `var addition = 0.0;` is the same as `double addition = 0.0`, so you know that it is non-nullable (value type). You cannot use null coalescing operator on a value type. 'twon't compile.